# What is some useful software for brainstorming/planning long trips?

Tags: planning, online-resources

I'm planning on taking my partner and his family on a trip around the UK next year, and I have a ton of ideas in my head that I want to have written down in some form that makes it easy to edit and move things around. So I'm looking for suggestions for software that ideally makes it easy to enter information about transport and hotels, as well as thoughts on potential destinations, day trips, etc. I have used [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com/), but it requires me to be a bit too specific with dates and times, I want something that is more flexible and lets me brainstorm without pinning me down to certain things.

Comment: I may be off but regarding "finding places to see", check out http://awespot.org

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but it's a good example of where pencil and paper is still far superior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://Duffelup.com. It can help you to plan a trip including transportations, activities, logging, daily trips, or any idea/notes you may have. It allows you to write down ideas without specifying dates and times. But you can definitely plan those specific timings when you're ready. Hope this helps.

Edit: Mindmapping softwares like [freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) might also work for you. But they are not specific for trip planning.

Comment: This was exactly the type of thing I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: It seems that duffelup.com is gone.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to consider some kind of online note-taking software, like [Evernote](http://evernote.com). It makes it easy to write notes, capture webpages as notes, etc.

Answer (score 4):

[freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a freeware mindmapping software. Mindmapping is a way of writing down a brainstorm in a [tree-shaped diagram](http://www.google.nl/images?q=mindmap).

[Edraw](http://www.edrawsoft.com/) has programs for making all kinds of diagrams, but it is not for free. (You can try the demo for free)

Answer (score 2):

If you own an iPad something like MindNode or iMindMap might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Creately](https://creately.com/). Its a tool that is built for planning, brainstorming or design anything, visually. It's a simple tool where you can map out your long trip on an infinite canvas. Add location pictures through Creately's built-in google image search tool, color pallet and drag and drop shapes and symbols to make your map interesting.  It has collaboration features that would make brainstorming fun with your team. It's free to try.